# In GNU GCC 4.5.3 type casting int to short

Tags: gcc, compiler-theory

I would like to know, when two integers are multiplied and result is typecast to short and assigned to short, what will the compiler resolves it to? Below is the code snippet

```
int a=1,b=2,c;
short x=3,y=4,z;

int p;
short q;

int main()
{

c = a*b; /* Mul two ints and assign to int
            [compiler resolves this to __mulsi3()] */

z = x*y; /* Mul two short and assign to short
            [compiler resolves this to __mulhi3()] */

p = (x*y); /* Mul two short and assign to int
              [compiler resolves this to __mulsi3()] */

q =(short)(a*b); /* Mul two ints typecast to short and assign to short
                    [compiler resolves this to __mulhi3()] */

return 0;

}
```

Here in the case for `q =(short)(a*b);`, first two ints multiplication should be performed (using `__mulsi3()`) and then assign it to short. But it's not the case here, compiler type casts both `a` and `b` to short and then calls `__mulhi3()`.

I would like to know how can I change in gcc source code [which file], so that i can achieve my above requirements.

Comment: Why do you care what instructions it generates? Is it producing incorrect results?

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can analyse the code and see that as you covert the result immediately to a `short` the mutiplication can be done as `short` multiplication without affecting the result. This is exactly the same as case two of your example.

As the result is the same you don't need to worry about which multiplication function is used.

Comment: The compiler is target specific and porting has being done. Hence i required the above changes to be implementedin the gcc source code.